# Desabilitar dia especifico - PikaDay

Tags: javascript, php

Bom dia, tenho um sistema de reserva de salão de um condominio. Quero saber como faço para desabilitar no proprio calendário o dia que já tem reserva para outro condômino não reservar na mesma data.

Estou usando PHP PDO para puxar as infos do banco de dados.

Segue código onde renderiza o calendário.

```
var $datePicker = $('[data-calendar]')[0];
var dataLocale = $('[data-calendar]').data('pikaday-locale');
var langs = {
previousMonth: 'Mês Anterior',
nextMonth: 'Mês Seguinte',
months: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
weekdays: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado'],
weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab']
};
var someDate = new Date(); 
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 90)
var picker = new Pikaday({
field: $datePicker,
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
i18n: langs,
minDate: moment().toDate(),
maxDate: someDate
})
```

Answer (score -3):

De acordo com o [readme](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration), você deve usar no construtor o parâmetro `disableDayFn`:

> `disableDayFn` callback function that gets passed a Date object for each
> day in view. Should return true to disable selection of that day.

Cada data visível no seletor chamará a função passada, com ela como argumento. Adaptando do exemplo e simplificando, ficaria assim:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),

    disableDayFn: function(theDate) {
       /*
           Aqui entra a lógica para desabilitar a data passada (theDate)
           Como exemplo só está verificando se é dia 5
       */
       var desabilitar = (theDate.getDate() === 5);
       return desabilitar;
       
    }
});
```

Se a função retornar true, a caixa referente à data fica desabilitada.
A lógica pode ser uma requisição ajax, uma consulta em um vetor montado ao carregar a página ou outra lógica que achar pertinente.

Como lembrete é também necessário fazer a validação no lado do servidor após envio do formulário.